# Uploading multiple files to server in php (More than one array on a page)

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload

This has had me stumped for a couple of days. I am trying to upload multiple files to the server. I am adding more than one array of files because each group of files is added a different prefix to the filename while it is copied to the server.

The first array uploads perfectly...

```
<input name="image[]" type="file" id="image[]" size="30">
<br><input name="image[]" type="file" id="image[]" size="30">
<br><input name="image[]" type="file" id="image[]" size="30">
<br><input name="image[]" type="file" id="image[]" size="30">
<br><input name="image[]" type="file" id="image[]" size="30">
```

But when I try to add another array nothing is uploaded...

```
<input name="image2[]" type="file" id="image2[]" size="30">
<br><input name="image2[]" type="file" id="image2[]" size="30">
<br><input name="image2[]" type="file" id="image2[]" size="30">
<br><input name="image2[]" type="file" id="image2[]" size="30">
<br><input name="image2[]" type="file" id="image2[]" size="30">
```

This is the code that processes the request...

```
//This works for the first array on the page
while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES[image][name])){    if(!empty($value)) {           
$filename = $prefix1.$value;         
$add = "../portfolio/gallery/upload/$filename";              
copy($_FILES[image][tmp_name][$key], $add);       
chmod("$add",0777);   
 }}


//This does not work for the second array on the page
while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES[image2][name])){    if(!empty($value)) {           
$filename = $prefix2.$value;         
$add = "../portfolio/gallery/upload/$filename";             
copy($_FILES[image2][tmp_name][$key], $add);       
chmod("$add",0777);   
 }}
```

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: you are missing some quotes there...

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that this is the error I am receiving when I try to upload the second group of files... Warning: copy() [function.copy]: Filename cannot be empty in

Comment: Hmmm, what quotes? Perhaps I have been looking at it wayyy to long to notice.

Comment: you could add another dimension to the image array and see if that makes a difference. `image[1][]` and `image[2][]`

Comment: I admit I have not used multidimensional arrays before. Something like this? <input name="image2[1][]" type="file" id="image2[1][]" size="30">

Comment: Don't need quotes around chmod '$add'

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the `image` key not the `image2` key in your second while loop at the copy command. Besides that you should add quotes around the array key names.

Here is a slightly improved and cleaned version of your script. It still has one big flaw, you are trusting user input which enabled attackers to copy files to random locations etc.

The [PHP Documentation has a nice entry about php file handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) where you can readup more about `move_uploaded_file` and file security.

```
<?php

foreach ($_FILES['image']['name'] AS $key => $filename) {
    if(!empty($filename)) {
        $add = "../portfolio/gallery/upload/" . $prefix1 . $filename;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key], $add);
        chmod($add, 0777);   
    }
}

foreach ($_FILES['image2']['name'] AS $key => $filename) {
    if (!empty($filename)) {
        $add = "../portfolio/gallery/upload/" . $prefix2 . $filename;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'][$key], $add);       
        chmod($add, 0777);   
    }
}
```

Comment: I corrected the image2 key and it still does not work. copy($_FILES[image2][tmp_name][$key], $add);

Comment: Please be more specific about "it does not work". Whats the error? Did you check the php error log?

Comment: Did you check the `upload_errors` value? Maybe there was an issue with the upload.

Comment: I am getting the following error: Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in....  Why isn't it being seen as an array? It's strange because the first array is being recognized and the files are copied to the server but the second array is not recognized.

Comment: Please update your first post with the current code.

Comment: Are the file inputs in the same html form? Do they both get send at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

If I var_dump($_FILES) I get the expected result, thus you might have an issue in the loop there, I tried to modify it in which it made sense as:

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="image[]" type="file" id="image[]" size="30">
<br><input name="image[]" type="file" id="image[]" size="30">
<br><input name="image[]" type="file" id="image[]" size="30">
<br><input name="image[]" type="file" id="image[]" size="30">
<br><input name="image[]" type="file" id="image[]" size="30">
<br><br>
<br><input name="image2[]" type="file" id="image[]" size="30">
<br><input name="image2[]" type="file" id="image[]" size="30">
<br><input name="image2[]" type="file" id="image[]" size="30">
<br><input name="image2[]" type="file" id="image[]" size="30">
<input type='submit'>
</form>
    <?php
    function move_to_root($name,$tmp, $prefix1, $value)
    {
        $filename = $prefix1.$name;         
        $add = "upload/$filename";              
        move_uploaded_file($tmp, $add);       
        chmod("$add",0777); 
    }
if(!empty($_FILES))
{
    $prefix = 'ab';//You should know
    $value  = 'cd';//the same
    $nrImages = count($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $nrImages2 = count($_FILES['image2']['name']);
    for($index=0; $index<=$nrImages; $index++)
    {
        if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'][$index]))
        move_to_root($_FILES['image']['name'][$index],$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$index], $prefix, $value);
    }

    for($index=0; $index<=$nrImages2; $index++)
    {
        if(!empty($_FILES['image2']['name'][$index]))
        move_to_root($_FILES['image2']['name'][$index],$_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'][$index], $prefix, $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tested it and it works fine :) the original post was with big errors, sorry

Comment: I just don't know what I am doing wrong. I am using your code exactly and it only uploads the first group of images.

Comment: I am clueless, have you checked the maximum upload size?

Comment: put a echo '<pre>';var_dump($_FILES);echo'</pre>'; and check for errors